# How to encode the response of an TIdHTTP call?

Tags: delphi, encoding, httpresponse, indy, delphi-10-seattle

In a project I use TIdHTTP to call a webserver.

The webserver is an asp.net test application that returns the following json:

```
{
   "message":"test ÀÈÉÌÒÙàèéìòù"
}
```

The response I get in Delphi is a kind of not encoded string:

`{"message":"test ÃÃÃÃÃÃÃ Ã¨Ã©Ã¬Ã²Ã¹"`}

this is how I use TIdHTTP:

```
Result := '';
  IdHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create;
  IdHTTP.Request.MethodOverride := 'ForwardCommand';
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL :=  TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(IdHTTP);
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.Mode       := sslmClient;
  IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.SSLOptions.SSLVersions:= [sslvTLSv1_2];
  IdHTTP.IOHandler := IdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
  IdHTTP.HandleRedirects := True;
  IdHTTP.Response.ContentEncoding := 'UTF-8'; // I tried this but it seems not enough! 
  try
    url := 'testappUrl';
    try
      IdHTTP.ConnectTimeout := 2000; 
      IdHTTP.ReadTimeout := 4000; 
      Response := IdHTTP.Get(url);
      ShowMessage(response);
    except
      on E:Exception do
      begin
        response := StringReplace(E.Message,#10,' ',[rfReplaceAll]);
        response := StringReplace(response,#13,' ',[rfReplaceAll]);
        response := '{"errormessage": "'+response+'"}';
      end;
    end;
    Result := response;
  finally
    IdHTTP.Free;
  end;
```

please tell me how I can see the response correctly.
Is there a way to force encoding so that accented chars are read correctly?

Thanks.

Comment: You must read `.Response.ContentEncoding` after having performed the `.Get()` and act upon it. But even if it is not `'UTF-8'` JSON as per standard must be UTF-8 encoded. Most likely the server doesn't explicitly send an encoding and `TIdHttp` then thinks it's some kind of ANSI.

Comment: Can you post the full server response (including HTTP headers)?

Comment: @AmigoJack afaik Indy does the decoding to Delphi UnicodeString automatically, based on the server-provided ContentEncoding

Comment: @mjn But it surely isn't intelligent enough to do that per MIME type `application/json` as per [RFC 4626 § 3](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) - for that the implementing client is responsible, but UnDiUdin does not even know that a HTTP response (and its encoding) can't be crafted when sending a request - he's most likely new to JSON.

Comment: the solution provided in the accepted answer did the job. Thanks for joining the dicsussion

Comment: @AmigoJack There is currently an [http-json-charset](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/tree/http-json-charset) branch in Indy's GitHub to correct that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try to use a `TStringStream` forcing the encoding (**UTF-8**).
Test this code to get the response:

```
var
  ts:TStringStream;
begin

  ...

  ts := TStringStream.Create(string.Empty, TEncoding.UTF8);
  IdHTTP1.Get('url', ts);

  ShowMessage(ts.DataString);
    or
  ShowMessage(ts.ToString);
  ...
```

Comment: Note that there is currently an [http-json-charset](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/tree/http-json-charset) branch in Indy's GitHub to correct this so that JSON gets decoded as UTF-8 properly when `Get()` returns a `string`.